# How to fit the img into the div when dimentions unknown

Tags: image, css-float, css

I have a small div (e.g. 200px x 200px) and some dynamically shown images: landscape, portrait or panorama dimensions (e.g. 600px X 300px; 200px X 600px ; 2000px X 300px)
I need to fit all of them in my div with CSS.
I have:

```
<div class="container">
 <img />
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.container {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
overflow:hidden
}
img.container {
min-height:100%;
min-width:100%;
}
```

But big images will be way bigger that the div. If i put max-height and max-width to 100% - than i have image starched. 
Basically i need to keep the bigger dimension equal 100% of the parent div. And show a part of the image. How do i do that without JS?

Answer (score 0):

```
img.container
```

will select any img tags with the container class, but your html doesn't have any.  Did you mean to use:

```
.container img {
```

to select an img that is a contained by an element with the container class?
If you set:

```
.container img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

The image width should fit in the div, but the height will be permitted to be shorter,  leaving some of the div's background visible; or longer, cutting off some of the image.

Edit:
I don't think the exact effect you want can be accomplished without javascript.
If you add an onload handler to the img element during the page ready function, you can auto-adjust each image when its src changes.  This jquery snippet accomplishes that:

```
$(function() {
        $(".container img").on('load',function() {
            if ($(this).height() > $(this).width()) {
                $(this).css('height','auto').css('width','100%');
            } else {
                $(this).css('height','100%').css('width','auto');
            }
        })
    })
```

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDWfT/) to demonstrate

Comment: Right, but i need no background to be visible. So if the height is more than with - cut off the height. If the width is more than height - cut off the width.

Comment: I don't know how to do that without branching.  There is supposed to be a calc function coming for css, but I'm not sure if/how well it is supported.

Comment: the calc function works pretty good with major latest browsers - however i mainly use it for margins... don't see any application here...

Comment: Would it be acceptable to set max-height: 200px on the container instead of height so the div shrinks a bit when the image is too short?

Comment: this is the problem - i don't want to shrink the image anyhow - really want to keep the initial ratio